# A matroid that is graphic in characteristic 2 but not in characteristic 3

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, matroids

Let $A$ be the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0& 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
in the field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $M_q[A]$ be the matroid associated to $A$. Prove that if $q=2$ then $M_q[A]$ is graphic, but it's not if $q=3$.

**My (primitive) attempt**

Clearly the rank of $A$ is $3$. And for $q=2$ clearly a set of $3$ columns is a basis iff their sum isn't equal to $0$ or one of the three columns. This allows me to write quite easily the list of basis of $M_2[A]$ so I have the list of the maximal subtrees of the graph. It's not clear to me how to construct a graph given its family of maximal subtrees.

For $q=3$ I have no clue on how to proceed...

Comment: To exhibit a graph in the case of $q=2$, observe that you can always use a connected graph, so that for a maximal subtree with 3 edges you can do with 4 vertices and 6 edges for the graph. If you start with a $K_{1,3}$ for the edges 1,2,3 you can see that the placement for the edges 4,5,6 is forced. This will also give you a hint about another set of dependent edges which is not present in the matrix representation for $q=3$.
~